# Samba server permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, samba, file-server

I have a Ubuntu server installed on the "server" with 5 users (+ root + transmission).
These 5 users (omichron_group) are ***windows/mac*** users.
I tried to read the samba manual/doc but i couldnt understand a sentence.

Here is the conf:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Omichron_server
    security = user 
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U


[omichron_share]
    path = /tarolo/share/omichron_share
    comment = Everyone can w,r,x (delete)
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    valid user = @omichron_group
    public = yes 
    create mask = 0755
    create mode = 0755
    directory mask = 0755


[homes]
    browseable = no
    writeable = yes
    valid users = %U
    force user = %U 
    create mask = 0755
    directory mask = 0755

    
[torrent]
        path = /tarolo/torrent
        comment = Torrent // 1TB disk, everyone r,w,x (delete)
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        valid user = @omichron_group
        public = yes
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
```

The directory's permissions:

```
**drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root            4096 Jan 14 13:44 home**
drwx------ 2 root     root           16384 Jan 13 19:51 lost+found
**drwxrwxr-x 3 omichron omichron_group  4096 Jan 14 13:48 share**
    drwxrwxr-x 2 omichron omichron_group 4096 Jan 28 14:01 omichron_share
**drwxrwxr-x 8 omichron omichron_group  4096 Feb 25 13:12 torrent**
```

**So, i would like to share:**

- every persons home directory (with full permission to the owner, but
  the others can't see it) /home
- a directory that every user can read, write, execute (and delete
  files) /share/omichron
- a directory that every user can read, write, execute and delete
  (torrent folder) /tarolo/torrent

**My questions:**

1. Will i need to use `winbind` and `kerberos`?
2. Will the `755` permission work or is should change?
3. If set `create mask, directory mask` to `755` do i have to change the directory permission    with `chmod`?
4. Who should be the owner of the shared folders?
5. If someone downloads a file via transmission can the user be the owner instead of transmission?

Sorry for my bad English and the horrible structure of this post. This was my first. I hope my questions are understandable,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web for this stuff. Please make the effort of reading them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will i need to use winbind and kerberos?

Most likely not. The Samba fileserver provides the same features regardless of where the accounts come from – your local Samba accounts are already automatically associated with the corresponding OS accounts, etc.

(However, Active Directory *would* be a good idea if you have more than 3-4 servers.)

> Who should be the owner of the shared folders?

Doesn't really matter; root would be a good choice if there's no specific owner otherwise.

> If set create mask, directory mask to 755 do i have to change the directory permission with chmod?

Depends on situation, but most likely "yes".

Samba's "create/directory mask" settings do not change existing permissions; they only specify what will be used for *new* files created on that share. If you want to make a public share but the directory currently has permissions 0700 – Samba won't change that; you have to chmod it yourself.

> Will the 755 permission work or is should change?

It's the standard "readable by others" permission. It doesn't really match your descriptions though – for home directories it'd grant too much (unnecessary 'read/execute' for others); for shared directories it'd grant too little (missing 'write' for others); so you probably need to change it in both cases.

> If someone downloads a file via transmission can the user be the owner instead of transmission?

Only if the users run *their own* Transmission instances (each on its own port number).

As Transmission is a local process, it is unaffected by SMB server configuration – all files it creates will be owned by the account that Transmission itself runs as.

Disable the system-wide Transmission service, then create a "user-level" transmission.service in `/etc/systemd/user/`, which each user could start using `systemctl --user`. (There are some differences in what settings to use, but those are already documented elsewhere.)

Don't forget to use `loginctl enable-linger` to allow the users' personal services start on boot (by default they're limited to login—logout, but the "linger" mode avoids that).